# How to use Tooltip with virtualSelectInput in R Shiny to show filter values if text is long and hidden by ellipsis

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinywidgets

I've a R shiny application in which I am using **virtualSelectInput** to show list of values for my filter. But some of my text values are long and the dropbox hides them by ellipsis(...).

I see that the Virtual Select [documentation](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/?id=get-started) mentions using Tooltip for displaying these long values while hovering cursor during value selection. But I couldn't figure out a way to use it in R Shiny.

I also found that R shiny has another function called **tooltipOptions** from same shinyWidgets library to show tooltip for a dropdown menu button. But again, there isn't any usage example.

I tried using it in below form through a dummy shiny app -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

options <- c(
  "This is short text",
  "This is a longer text",
  "This is a very very very very long text",
  "This is a super ultra pro max very very very very long text"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Virtual Select Input Example"),
  
  virtualSelectInput("selected_option", "Select Digital Thread:", choices = options, 
                     multiple = TRUE, search = TRUE, searchNormalize = TRUE, position = "auto", dropboxWidth = "250px", 
                     showSelectedOptionsFirst = TRUE, placeholder = "All", markSearchResults = TRUE, selectAllOnlyVisible = TRUE,
                     tooltipOptions = tooltipOptions(placement = "right", title = "Params", html = FALSE)),
  
  textOutput("selected_value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$selected_value <- renderText({
    paste("You selected:", input$selected_option)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But it doesn't work. I know I am not correctly using these together, so I would appreciate if someone can guide on using it either through this or any other simple way.
I am not very inclined towards using a custom css or js code because in my real application I have Virtual Select at almost 100 different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things to do:

- the **virtual-select** JavaScript library has been updated yesterday in **shinyWidgets**, and you have to install this version (`remotes::install_github("dreamRs/shinyWidgets")`);
- you have to set the option `showValueAsTags = TRUE`;
- you have to download **tooltip.min.js** and **tooltip.min.css** [here](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/?id=download-files), include them in the ***www*** subfolder of your app and then:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$scrip(src = "tooltip.min.js"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "tooltip.min.css")
  ),
  titlePanel("Virtual Select Input Example"),

  virtualSelectInput(
    "selected_option", "Select Digital Thread:", choices = options,
    multiple = TRUE,
    showValueAsTags = TRUE),
  ......
```

I'm going to inform the author of **shinyWidgets** that these two additional files should be added in the package.

Comment: I tried with the mentioned development version from github and it worked even without downloading the tooltip.min.js and tooltip.min.css files. I didn't even have to add these to my tags$head and yet I was able to see the tooltip when I ran my app.

So, I've two questions - 

1 - What do you think made it work without those files and will it be okay if I use it without those ?
2 - Since my Shiny app is a production application, I doubt I will be able to use this development package of shinyWidgets in it. So, is it something I can expect from the CRAN version of shinyWidgets anytime soon ?

Comment: @Shubham That's me who updated **shinyWidgets** in the meantime. I don't know when the author intends to release this new version.

Comment: I think in that case I'd wait for the release of this new version. Many thanks for this update though!

Comment: @Shubham it has been released today or yesterday

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this, is increasing the size of `dropboxWidth` to `500px`. And then you can have this result:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Virtual Select Input Example"),
  
  virtualSelectInput("selected_option", "Select Digital Thread:", 
                     choices = options, 
                     multiple = TRUE, 
                     search = TRUE, 
                     searchNormalize = TRUE, 
                     position = "auto", 
                     dropboxWidth = "500px", # Change this parameter
                     showSelectedOptionsFirst = TRUE, 
                     placeholder = "All", 
                     markSearchResults = TRUE, selectAllOnlyVisible = TRUE,
                     tooltipOptions = tooltipOptions(placement = "right", 
                                      title = "Params", html = FALSE)),
  
  textOutput("selected_value")
)
```

[image]